# Why the move constructor isn't invoked?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

I defined a class with both copy and move constructors. The copy constructor seems to work fine but when I try to invoke the move constructor it doesn't work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A{

        public:
                A() = default;

                A(A& a){
                        std::cout << "Copy constructor." << std::endl;
                };

                A(A&& a){
                        std::cout << "Move constructor." << std::endl;
                };
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        auto a = A(A());
        
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;       

        auto b = A(a);

        return 0;
}
```

I expect the `auto a = A(A());` should invoke move constructor because its input (`A()`) is an `rvalue`. But the output is this:

```
[amirreza@localhost tmp]$ ./a.out 
here
Copy constructor.
```

Is my assumption wrong?

I'm using `gcc` version `10.3.1` without explicitly specifying the c++ version.

Comment: The copy constructor should take a `const` reference, I would say. Which line produces the output you quoted?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong.  `auto a = A(A());` is allowed to simply call the default constructor, and since C++17 it is required that the move be elided.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think this `auto b = A(a);`

Comment: @DrewDormann would you give more info? or link to read more?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: Can you find out which line causes it and [edit] your question to clarify? Also, which C++ version are you targetting?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's safe to assume that `A(a)` is the source of the call to the constructor taking an lvalue reference...

Comment: Because the language has constraints and requirements for constructor semantics, **copy elision** can happen which will cause *side-effects* (like `std::cout`) to not occur.  This has been part of C++ for a very long time (as a possible compiler optimization), and as of C++17 is *required* behavior.

Comment: Standard reference: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.6.1